# SPSS match files results in empty column

Tags: merge, spss

I am trying to merge 2 files:

The first (mydata) has the examinees' data, which includes the langauge the examinee took the test (language) and the time it took them to complete the test (examinee_test_time).

In the second file (a table file named languages) gives the total test time (total_test_time) for each langauge.

Here is my syntax to merge the 2 files (after sorting each file):

```
MATCH FILES
  /FILE=*
 /TABLE=languages
 /BY language.
EXECUTE.
```

after the merge, the total test time variable is empty in the merged file.
What is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two simple reasons for this to happen:

1. your original file "mydata" already contains an empty field called
   `total_test_time` and so it doesn't get imported from "languages".
2. There are no corresponding values of `language` in the two files. It might seem there are but there are differences because of leading/trailing spaces, invisible charachters or capitalization.

Please check if any of these reasons applies.

Comment: Thanks! The langauges were written differently in the 2 files (with and without capitalization) :(